# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

When i try to click on the button several time then i encountered this error.
Below are the error in logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.huiiy.myapplication, PID: 3933
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.huiiy.myapplication.Activity9$13.onClick(Activity9.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5712)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22514)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Below are the coding of my application:

```
    iv_33.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MediaPlayer ivbsound = new MediaPlayer();
            ivbsound = MediaPlayer.create(Activity9.this,R.raw.ivbutton);
            //          MediaPlayer ivbsound = MediaPlayer.create(Activity9.this,R.raw.ivbutton);
            ivbsound.start();
            int theCard = Integer.parseInt((String) view.getTag());
            doStuff(iv_33, theCard);
        }
    });
```

Comment: But i have initialize the variable suppose not to hit null pointer exception in this point.

Comment: Look twice: you reassign `ivbsound = MediaPlayer.create()` ... must then return null. That is the thing. Android is tricky, you have to really understand when the framework does what.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, this is the one cause error, thank you so much buddy! the problem resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Try to create player with another audio file.
Maybe the ivbutton file is corrupt

[UPDATE]

If you are reusing it declare lazy property of this sound player and on every click play it

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer soundPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ivbutton);

        iv_33.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            soundPlayer.start();
            int theCard = Integer.parseInt((String) view.getTag());
            doStuff(iv_33, theCard);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for suggestion, but the file is working file since after i click on 8th or 9th time then cause the application crashed and show me this error and before that the sound was played as well.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the creation of your MediaPlayer failed (maybe you have warn/debug messages about it).
It's useless to create a new MediaPlayer and then replace it by a new one.

Check if R.raw.ivbutton exist and correspond to a good media (which can be runned).

Personnally, this is how I do:

```java
    File mediaFile = obj.getFile();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaFile.setReadable(true); // be sure that the program have access to the media content
        
        // this try/catch is to support multiple Android version
        try {
             mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
             mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
        }
    
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // prepare it, after you can change volume ...
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start(); // finally start the media
```

Answer (score 1):

please make sure that your sound file format you try to play is supported one check list from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats). as the MediaPlayer.create returns null in case of the file is not supported which cause you null pointer exception. besides i recommend to check if(ivbsound != null) before calling ivbsound.start();